# Typeahead that makes it clear whether you've selected an extant entity or are creating a new one

Tags: forms, gui-design, web-app

We have a typeahead that lets users identify a dog in our database (by name) or specify the name of a new dog to be added to the database.

Is there a good UI pattern that helps make it crystal clear whether the user has selected an extant entity or is creating a new one? Any examples would be helpful!

Answer (score 0):

I have not seen your UI so i don't know how you want them to be separated. I think using "breadcrumb" could possibly solve your problem. If you want to separate the headings you can just change the sub-headings to 'creating a new entity' or something.

[image]